# Does static_pointer_cast update reference counting

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have recently found out about replacing:

```
std::shared_ptr<NEWT>(static_cast<NEWT>(old_ptr.get()));
```

with

```
std::static_pointer_cast<NEWT>(odl_ptr);
```

I know that the former solution may result in double delete if one is not careful.

I was wondering if the reference counting is updated with the latter solution, and how is that achievable?

Comment: @BaummitAugen , lol typo!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using static_pointer_cast or dynamic_pointer_cast enables the generated shared_ptr to do **proper reference counting** without resulting in double deletes. This is achieved by calling a special constructor for the resulting casted pointer, here is an example implementation:

```
template< class T, class U > 
std::shared_ptr<T> static_pointer_cast( const std::shared_ptr<U>& r ) noexcept
{
    auto p = static_cast<typename std::shared_ptr<T>::element_type*>(r.get());
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(r, p);
}
```

Notice that the constructor called is

```
std::shared_ptr<T>(r,p);
```

which actually is of the form

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr );
```

The latter is an *aliasing constructor*, meaning that the object is managed by r, and the constructed shared_ptr is unamanaged. To have the same behaviour without the static_cast_pointer one would have to write

```
std::shared_ptr<T>(r, static_cast<T>(odl_ptr.get());
```

where your old_ptr is of some other type.

*some code from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)*